# Linq to Entities : how to handle null values in database with a contains

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am using EF4.

I want to write the following statement using linq to entities

```
select * from address where address.satausId in (1,2,3,4)
```

Status Id in the database may be null

I have tried

```
var statusesToFind = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};

var AddressList = from sa in db.Address
                  where statusesToFind.Contains(sa.statusId)
                  select sa;
```

this gives me a syntax error

The odd thing is, if I try the statement as above but using sa.Id, which is the key field, it works without a problem, I think the problem is due to to the fact that statusId in the database allows nulls.

I would appreciate if someone could please tell me how to write the above correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

make statustofind a list of nullable ints like

```
var statusesToFind = new List<int?> {1, 2, 3, 4};

var AddressList = from sa in db.Address
                  where statusesToFind.Contains(sa.statusId)
                  select sa;
```

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, much appreciated.